# What are the possible effects of changing my Salesforce.com Organization name?

Tags: salesforce

One of my clients wants to change their Salesforce Organization name. I know how to do this but was wondering if their may be ramifications if other third party applications are leveraging the name of the Organization? Would any of the existing installed apps be effected?

Thanks you in advance.
Graham

Answer (score 3):

Any third party application worthy of the name uses your SFDC org ID, which is immutable.  If you don't use it for anything internally (I would expect email templates to be the major offenders), you could change it once a day without any ill effects.

Edit:  That being said, you can always change it in your sandbox and see what explodes.

Comment: change it once a day, why? Graham wants to change it one time only, seems you mistakenly recommending to change it every day :)

Comment: Thanks offbyone (great name). That's preety much what I expected. I'm not sure if they have a sandbox but if they do I will try there first.

Comment: Hi Chirag, I think he just means, I "could" change it once a day if I needed to without any ill effects.